# Pass by reference for blocks

Tags: objective-c-blocks

Is there a way to pass blocks by reference? 
Below code prints out "Block is nil"

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    void (^block)(void) = nil;
    [self assignBlock:block];

    if ( block ) {block();}
    else{NSLog(@"Block is nil");}

    return YES;
}

- (void)assignBlock:(void (^)(void))blockToAssign
{
    blockToAssign = ^(void){
        NSLog(@"Block assigned");
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Declare a type:

```
typedef void (^MyBlock)();
```

Redefine the function assignBlock receiving a pointer:

```
- (void)assignBlock:(MyBlock *)blockToAssign
{
    // assign the object pointing, not the pointer
    *blockToAssign = ^(void){
        NSLog(@"Block assigned");
    };
}
```

Now initialize the block using the type:

```
MyBlock block = nil;
```

When you call the function pass the address of the block:

```
[self assignBlock:&block];

if ( block ) {block();}
else{NSLog(@"Block is nil");}
```

Comment: Perfect! I assumed you could, but couldn't figure out the syntax. Thanks!

Comment: @ErikRodriguez: the correct expanded syntax would be `- (void)assignBlock:(void (^*)(void))blockToAssign`